# how to write a query in oracle to get a single value as string from the json list?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a json string containing list of data, I want to write a query to get a single value based on the condition. but it is returning list of values. please help me to write a valid query in oracle database.

My json string looks like

```
[
{
  "Key": [
    {
      "obj": {
        "xyz":"cdf"
      },
      "Info": [
        {
          "Code": "",
          "tax": "",
          "rate": "",
          "taxAmount": {
            "formattedAmount": "",
            "Amount": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "Code": "qwer",
          "tax": "ggs",
          "rate": "0",
          "taxAmount": {
            "formattedAmount": "10.00",
            "Amount": "10.00"
          },
          "key": "qwer"
        },
        {
          "Code": "poiu",
          "tax": "ggs",
          "rate": "0",
          "taxAmount": {
            "formattedAmount": "20.00",
            "Amount": "20.00"
          },
          "key": "poiu"
        },
        {
          "coverageCode": "zxcv",
          "tax": "ggs",
          "rate": "0",
          "taxAmount": {
            "formattedAmount": "30.00",
            "Amount": "30.00"
          },
          "key": "zxcv"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "status": "S"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I want to get formattedAmount value "10.00". Written a query like

```
SELECT json_query(details, '$.Info.taxAmount.formattedAmount' WITH WRAPPER) 
FROM details_table where json_query(details, '$.Info.Code' WITH WRAPPER) = 'qwer';
```

returns no value. without where clause i'll get all the formattedAmont in list [,"10.00","20.00","30.00"]

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: What happens if you omit  WITH WRAPPER ?

Comment: without wrapper it returns null

Comment: And if you enclose ["qwer"] ?

Comment: No values if I enclose ["qwer"]. Tried with both like operator and equals operator.

Comment: I don't think `json_query` works like you think it does. According to manuals, `json_query` is a simple string function that will extract all the values according to the path you give it, so `json_query(details, '$.Info.Code' WITH WRAPPER)` will get you something like `["qwer", "poiu", "zxcv"]`, and `json_query(details, '$.Info.taxAmount.formattedAmount' WITH WRAPPER)` will work regardless of what's specified in "where" clause. You're trying to treat JSON string as relational table, so look into `json_table` function.